# How do I pass parameters to a Python function?

Tags: python, function, printing, formula

I am trying to use this function found online to calculate the distance between two latitude and longitude points on the Earth.

However, I do not know how to pass my values for latitude and longitude because I replace `lat1`, `lon1` and `lat2`, `lon2`,  and I get an error every time.

Where do i put in the values I want for latitude and longitude?

```
import math

def distance(origin, destination):
    lat1, lon1 = origin
    lat2, lon2 = destination
    radius = 6371 # km

    dlat = math.radians(lat2-lat1)
    dlon = math.radians(lon2-lon1)
    a = math.sin(dlat/2) * math.sin(dlat/2) + math.cos(math.radians(lat1)) \
        * math.cos(math.radians(lat2)) * math.sin(dlon/2) * math.sin(dlon/2)
    c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))
    d = radius * c

    return d
```

EDIT:
For example, if I have

```
lat1 = 20 and lon1 = 100 
lat2 = 30 and lon2 = 110
```

why does it fail when I replace lon1 with the number in the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
distance((lat1, lon1), (lat2, lon2))
```

Notice that the function receives as parameters two two-element tuples (or two two-element lists, it'd be the same), each one representing a (latitude, longitude) pair. Equivalently:

```
origin = (lat1, lon1)
destination = (lat2, lon2)
distance(origin, destination)
```

Comment: Im still confused as how to use this as I keep getting error when I try to execute. Say my lat1 = 20 and my lon1 = 100 and lat2 = 30 and lon2 = 110 how would I then put those numbers into your equation and the whole function. Thanks

Comment: Like this: `distance((20, 100), (30, 200))`

Comment: Lopez please can you edit the intial code above because Im trying yours and it wont work at all because i keep getting invalid syntax when i type in the tuples as you have shown

Comment: It works for me, exactly as I wrote above. You must be doing something else wrong, but my answer is correct, I even tested it with the example, it returns `9818.324994648268`.

Comment: Im confused i type it in as above but cant get the code to work for some reason. Could it be because im using python 2.7? Could you rewrite the whole code out because i must be placing your code in the wrong spot in the function then

Comment: Look at the link posted by Rob, there's nothing wrong in the code, the link shows that it's in fact working. It doesn't matter if it's Python 2.7. Try typing the whole thing again, maybe it's a problem with white space. Or use a decent IDE. Sorry, but the problem is in your computer, the code is right.

Comment: Thanks all i have it working now it was indeed a whitespace error Oscar :)

Answer (score 0):

You could call it with named parameters by passing tuples for each one, like:

```
distance(origin=origin_tuple, destination=dest_tuple)
```

Where

```
origin_tuple = (origin_lat , origin_long)
dest_tuple = (dest_lat , dest_long)
```